# Writeback to AS Cube via SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssas

is there a way that you can writeback to an Analysis Service Cube(SSAS) through the Reporting Services(SSRS)?

What our Customer wants is an easy interface in SSRS to write his Cube data, but I dind't found a way to do this. The only idea I had was writing some MDX inserts that will throw the data in there.

Is there an other, easy way to do this with SRSS? The customer said he doesn't want to do this in Excel (with Excel it's easy).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but probably a very bad idea. You can have your dataset query be an MDX insert statement and use the report parameters to determine what will be inserted. However, I would strongly caution against this. SSRS is not the best tool to perform data updates with. I've only had one situation I ever encountered where having a button to perform an update made sense on a report.

Answer (score -2):

No SSRS cannot be used as a user input tool.   There is no way for a user to type something into an SSRS report and have it update a cube or database.   SSRS is only for displaying data to the user.

If the customer doesn't want to use Excel, your other options would be Access or a custom .net interface.